YouTube Analytics shows the number of viewers, but the YouTube Reporting API does not show the number of viewers
I have created set of YouTube Reporting API jobs for a YouTube channel. The jobs were created and run every day as scheduled. However when I go to download the jobs they are all blank, only the header is displayed.
I checked the YouTube Reporting API job data from 3 days ago, and all the data was blank.
On the YouTube Analytics screen of YouTube Studio, data for the same day was able to be obtained.
I also checked the OAth2 authentication associations and channels, and there were no errors in the settings.
Why might my reports be empty and how can I fix this?
I downloaded data from 3 days ago using the Windows curl command.
As a result of running the command, only the header is displayed and all data is blank.

C:\Windows\System32> curl -X GET "https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/CHANNEL/<channelID>/jobs/<jobID>/reports/<reportID>?alt=media" -H "Authorization: Bearer <access-token>"
date,channel_id,video_id,live_or_on_demand,subscribed_status,country_code,views,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,watch_time_minutes,average_view_duration_seconds,average_view_duration_percentage,annotation_impressions,annotation_clickable_impressions,annotation_clicks,annotation_click_through_rate,annotation_closable_impressions,annotation_closes,annotation_close_rate,card_teaser_impressions,card_teaser_clicks,card_teaser_click_rate,card_impressions,card_clicks,card_click_rate,subscribers_gained,subscribers_lost,videos_added_to_playlists,videos_removed_from_playlists,red_views,red_watch_time_minutes
C:\Windows\System32>

